# How can I remove the last comma from a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string coming in from raw data.  I can't guarantee that there might or might not be an extra comma.  I thought I might be able to remove it like this:

```
$value = "cat, dog, fish, ";

$value =~ s/,//r;
```

Sadly that doesn't work.  Of course I could do a loop to check the last char of the string one by one, but I would like to learn how to do it with the Regex backslash method.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$value =~ s/,\s*$//;
```

The pattern `,\s*$` matches a comma (`,`) followed by zero or more space-chars (`\s*`), followed by the end of the line/input (`$`).

Comment: Thank you @bartkiers that was it.  I am still trying to learn Regex. Can I assume that if we leave out the '*' that it would only work if the line ended with a comma and just one whitespace?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note that `\s` not only matches a space, but also tabs, new line chars (and possible other unicode space characters)

Answer (score 4):

`s/,//` removes the first comma. So,

```
$value = reverse(reverse($value) =~ s/,//r);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "tlle character"?

Comment: Sorry,  in a hurry I did not use the regular expression , ~ , the tilde operator , when  I just copy-pasted it. So perhaps not surprisingly, I ended up with an empty string. Since other responders often used it in a full form, rather ready to use , when I was testing other options, so for a few whiles I got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are specifying /r in your code but not using the return value.  If in fact you are using it, add it back.

```
s/.*\K,//
```

Ah, if there may not be a trailing comma that you don't want, this won't work; it will always delete the last comma.  Use Bart's answer then.

Comment: This requires `/s` if the string can contain newlines.

Comment: I missed that this solution was already suggested so I'll add my explanation here. The key to remember with regex is that it always works left to right and that each component will match as much as possible individually while still allowing the whole expression to match. This means that the `.*` will first try matching the whole string, then backtrack until it matches as much of the string as it can while still having a following comma. The `\K` then prevents anything before the comma from being replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer removes a comma followed by zero or more white space characters at the end of a string. But you asked about removing the last comma. Either is consistent with your example, but if you really want to remove the last comma, one way is:

```
$value =~ s/,([^,]*$)/$1/
```

This will, for example, change `"foo,bar,baz"` to `"foo,barbaz", and in your example`"cat, dog, fish, "`to`"cat, dog, fish "` (leaving the trailing space).

The `reverse` trick in choruba's answer also works.

If nothing else, this shows the importance of a precise problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using positive look ahead,

```
$value =~ s/,(?=[^,]*\z)//;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this pattern: `,*\s*$`. It matches all commas (if any) and all white spaces (if any) and the end of the string.

A full example:

```
use 5.18.2;
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = "cat, dog, fish,,,,,,,,,,,,,                          ";                                                                                   
$data =~ s/,*\s*$// ;
print $data;
```